# I want to edit entry with Wpforms in frontend...how?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wpforms

I create a info page using WPforms for user in frontend, and now i want to create an update page with WPforms. please show me the way to do that? wpforms doesn't have a shortcode to load data to form like "[wpforms entry_id=***]".

If i must buy a plugin, please tell me the name of plugin like this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.